# Python number limitation on calculation(not on float)

Tags: python

I'm doing codeforces and found in huge number, my simple code started to make some bugs.

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(n):
    candies = sum(map(int,input().split()))
    if candies % 2 == 0:
        print(int(candies/2))
    else:
        print(int((candies-1)/2))
```

when I put

```
1
9547116602436426 8316250877914575 2981260158260522
```

I expected to see '10422313819305761' but what I get is '10422313819305760'.
But in other small numbers, of all combination in odd and even numbers, it worked very well. I used math.floor instead of if as well, but it gave me same answer.
Is there any limit on huge numbers in python?

Comment: But you *are* using floats - the division produces a float.

Comment: use `/` for float division and use `//` int(absolute) division ie 3/2=1.5 and 3//2=1

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Yes. But I divide even number by 2 so I thought there won't be any problem because of it :( But I guess it was problem. But thank you anyway!

Comment: @sahasrara62 Yes I could solve problem with this method. As upper mention said I guess it was the problem of float. Thank you!